# Destroy an on-screen tkinter label and then create another

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, label

I'm creating a BMI calc that works fine, however, once it has displayed the result label if someone enters a different value and a new label is made the previous one still remains.

I'm trying to code it so that the first label disappears once the calc function is rerun but I can't get it to work. No matter where I put the "destroyLabel()" function it causes an error as the "lblResult" label isn't defined even when I set it as a global.

Is there any solution to this?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()  # creates the GUI window
window.title("BMI")  # labels the window title
window.geometry("300x230")  # sets the window size

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="Calculator.png")  # sets the window icon
window.iconphoto(False, photo)

global lblResult

def destroyLabel():
    lblResult.destroy()

def calc():
    try:
        height = float(entry1.get())  # gets the height from the height box and converts to float
        weight = float(entry2.get())  # gets the weight from the height box and converts to float
        bmi = weight / (height ** 2)  # formula and logic to calculate bmi

        if bmi < 16:
            lblResult = tk.Label(window,
                                 text="Severely underweight",
                                 fg="blue")
        elif 16 <= bmi < 18.5:
            lblResult = tk.Label(window,
                                 text="Underweight",
                                 fg="green")
        elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
            lblResult = tk.Label(window,
                                 text="Healthy",
                                 fg="goldenrod")
        elif 25 <= bmi < 30:
            lblResult = tk.Label(window,
                                 text="Overweight",
                                 fg="orange")
        elif bmi >= 30:
            lblResult = tk.Label(window,
                                 text="Severely overweight",
                                 fg="red")
    except:
        lblResult = tk.Label(window,
                             text="Error!",
                             fg="red")
    lblResult.grid(row=7, column=1)  # adds the result label to the GUI



lblTitle = tk.Label(window,  # sets the title on screen
                    text="BMI Calculator",
                    font="Arial 14 bold",
                    )
lblTitle.grid(row=0, column=0)

lblSpace = tk.Label(window)  # adds a blank line to space out labels
lblSpace.grid(row=1, column=0)

lblHeight = tk.Label(window,  # sets the height label on screen
                     text="Height in metres",
                     font="Arial 10 bold",
                     )
lblHeight.grid(row=2, column=0)

lblWeight = tk.Label(window,  # sets the weight label on screen
                     text="Weight in KG",
                     font="Arial 10 bold",
                     )
lblWeight.grid(row=3, column=0)

entry1 = tk.Entry(window)  # creates a text box for the user to type
entry1.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(1, 1), pady=(1, 1))  # places entry 1 on the screen
entry2 = tk.Entry(window)  # creates a text box for the user to type
entry2.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(1, 1), pady=(1, 1))  # places entry 2 on the screen below entry 1

lblSpace = tk.Label(window)  # adds a blank line to space out labels
lblSpace.grid(row=4, column=0)

btnCalc = tk.Button(window,  # creates a button to calculate the BMI
                    text="Calculate BMI",
                    font="Arial 12 bold",
                    fg="red",
                    command=lambda: calc()
                    )
btnCalc.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=(1, 1), pady=(1, 1))  # places the button on the screen

btnQuit = tk.Button(window,  # creates a button to close the window
                    text="Quit",
                    font="Arial 12 bold",
                    fg="red",
                    width="12",
                    command=lambda: window.destroy()
                    )
btnQuit.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(1, 1), pady=(1, 1))  # places the button on the screen

lblSpace = tk.Label(window)  # adds a blank line to space out labels
lblSpace.grid(row=6, column=0)

lblBMI = tk.Label(window,  # adds the BMI label
                  text="BMI: ",
                  font="Arial 12 bold")
lblBMI.grid(row=7, column=0)

window.mainloop()  # triggers the window to open
```

Comment: We've had two other almost identical questions in less then a week. The answer is always: create the label once, then change the text on the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dynamically creating a new `lblResult` for each BMI case, you should create a single label and update its value when necessary

```
# SOME CODE HAS BEEN OMITTED FOR BREVITY
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()  # creates the GUI window
window.title("BMI")  # labels the window title
window.geometry("300x230")  # sets the window size

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="Calculator.png")  # sets the window icon
window.iconphoto(False, photo)

lblResult = tk.Label(window)
lblResult.grid(row=7, column=1)  # adds the result label to the GUI


def calc():
    try:
        height = float(entry1.get())
        weight = float(entry2.get())
        bmi = weight / (height ** 2)  # calculate bmi

        if bmi < 16:
            lblResult.configure(text="Severely underweight", fg="blue")
        elif 16 <= bmi < 18.5:
            lblResult.configure(text="Underweight", fg="green")
        elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
            lblResult.configure(text="Healthy", fg="goldenrod")
        elif 25 <= bmi < 30:
            lblResult.configure(text="Overweight", fg="orange")
        elif bmi >= 30:
            lblResult.configure(text="Severely overweight", fg="red")
    except:
        lblResult.configure(text=text="Error!", fg="red")
```